# objective-C : Reset tableview loaded with feltching objects (core data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, object

i have a tableview application loaded with core data feltching objects and i wanna know if it is possible to reset the table with a simple button. Thanks

code to add an object :

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];




[newManagedObject setValue:string forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

my code to delete (one) object:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

i want a button that reset the tableview and delete everything 
thanks

Comment: I don't know what "core data fetching objects" are - can you extend your question with the code where you load in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [datasource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource) to an empty one, and use the [reloadData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) method to reload the table data from that datasource?

Comment: but what is my data source? im using feltching objects i don't know how to put the datasource to empty.